# ant depends vs. antcall

Tags: java, ant, build-process, build-automation

When defining sequential build steps I use the `depends` attribute of the `target` element. I have recently seen an ant file, where the build sequence was defined by `antcall` elements inside the targets. 
To illustrate :

```
<target name="a" depends="b">
...</target>
```

vs

```
<target name="a">
<antcall target="b"/>
...</target>
```

Is there a real difference between the two approaches? Is one of them preferable?

Comment: The only time **antcall** is necessary is when you are migrating from ant to gradle, and calling ant targets from gradle.  In that case, your ant buildfile may not execute the **depends** targets, in which case you will need to use `antcall`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The main difference between both approaches is that targets in `depends` are *always* executed, while targets in `antcall` are executed only if the containing target is.

A clarifying example:

```
<target name="a" depends="b" if="some.flag">

</target>
```

Here, `b` will always be executed, while `a` will be executed only if `some.flag` is defined.

```
<target name="a" if="some.flag">
    <antcall target="b" />
</target>
```

Here, `b` will only be executed if `a` is, i.e. if `some.flag` is defined.

Comment: To add to this, a target can be invoked multiple times with `<antcall>` whereas a target might be executed at most once if all references to them are done via dependencies.

Comment: `depends` aren't **always** executed.  One example is when importing the ant script from gradle, and calling the main target from gradle.  In that case, that main target's `depends` aren't executed.

Answer (score 90):

The biggest difference is that Ant will ensure that dependencies declared via `depends` are called *at most once.*  For example:

```
<target name="a" />

<target name="b" depends="a" />

<target name="c" depends="a" />

<target name="d" depends="b, c" />
```

If I call target `d`, `b` and `c` are called.  However, `a` is only called once (even though both `b` and `c` depends on it).

Now suppose we decide to use `antcall` instead of depends for target `d`:

```
<target name="d">
   <antcall target="b" />
   <antcall target="c" />
</target>
```

Calling target `d` will now call targets `b` and `c`; however, target `a` will get called twice, once for `b` and then again for `c`.

In other words, `antcall` sidesteps the normal dependency rules that are the cornerstone of Ant.

I don't think `antcall` should be used as a substitute for normal Ant-like dependencies; that's what `depends` is for.  So when would you use it?  The `antcall` task does allow you to control what properties and references are defined (which is why a new Ant environment is created--and why it's so slow) so it can be used to create variants of the same thing; e.g., maybe two jars, one with and one without debug symbols.

Overusing `antcall`, however, creates slow, brittle, and hard to maintain build scripts.  Think of it as the `goto` of Ant--it's evil. Most well-written build scripts simply don't need it except in unusual cases.

Comment: Thank you, a highly relevant detail

Comment: I used to use antcall in order to set up "parameterized" targets that I could re-use, but the macrodef added in 1.6 a long while back makes for a much better case for this kind of reuse.

Comment: +1 for the comment about jars with different flavors. I was able to get my run-once part to run and still generate different flavors by moving the run-once part higher up in the hierarchy, so that it wouldn't be called by the antcall parts or their dependencies.

Answer (score 15):

Antcall is relatively rarely used, because:

> The called target(s) are run in a new
>   project; be aware that this means
>   properties, references, etc. set by
>   called targets will not persist back
>   to the calling project.

In other words, antcall is whole new isolated Ant process running.

Comment: does this also mean the antcall'ed tasks run in parallel?

Comment: No, antcall is synchronous, just like any other task. There is a <parallel> task in Ant for concurrent execution.

Comment: When I look at the documentation I see such quote: "By default, all of the properties of the current project will be available in the new project. Alternatively, you can set the inheritAll attribute to false and only "user" properties (i.e., those passed on the command-line) will be passed to the new project." https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html. This is something different than you said.

Answer (score 8):

antcall is the GOTO of ant. It is terrible. It's a great way to make a rats nest of unmaintainable cruft.  Next to ant-contrib it's the best way to smell an overly complicated hard to maintain ant file. (even a good antfile is rough)

If your depends are set properly you should be able to run any target up to that point successfully, unlike the antcall pattern.

Another reason nobody has touched on is vizant, the ability to generate a graph of your target dependencies is pretty sweet if it's a complicated build.  If you use antcall you're screwed.

I wish @Vladimir Dyuzhev was correct that antcall is rarely used - I've been to a lot of shops where it's the norm.

Comment: Antcall is a very convenient way to extract repeating steps into a separate task, and call it with different parameters. If vizant cannot support antcall, this is a problem of vizant, alas.

Comment: no. categorically no.  program flow in ant is done with depends, antcall calling into the same build.xml is an abomination.   If you need to do a similar thing many times with different inputs you're always better off using an ant  macro.

Comment: also - properties in ant aren't parameters

Comment: Unlike vizant, Grand (https://github.com/ggtools/Grand) does show the dependencies from <antcall>.

Comment: Scripts using antcall are a PITA :-( No reason to use antcall anymore after macrodef has been introduced with  ant 1.6 in 2003 !

Answer (score 0):

```
  <target name="a" depends="b"> ...</target>
```

This means beforeing executing any statement or any tag from target a, ANT makes it sure that target b is executed successfully

And you can call any target using antcall after some statements or tags gets executed from calling target.